# GraphET Pharo Smalltalk Labelling

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have this method which displays a chart using Graph-ET:

```
displayChart: aPGResult
"Takes result of SQL query and calculates duration from activityend MINUS activitystart and draws bars of duration length (in days)"

| diagram values names |
values := OrderedCollection new.
names := OrderedCollection new.
aPGResult rows do: [:row | | data duration actStart actEnd a b monthA monthB job |
data := row rawData.
a := data at: 2.
b := data at: 3.
job := data at: 1.
monthA := (a copyFrom: 6 to: 7) asInteger.
monthB := (b copyFrom: 6 to: 7) asInteger.
actStart := Date newDay: ((a copyFrom: 9 to: 10) asInteger) month: (months at: monthA) year: ((a copyFrom: 1 to: 4) asInteger).
actEnd := Date newDay: ((b copyFrom: 9 to: 10) asInteger) month: (months at: monthB) year: ((b copyFrom: 1 to: 4) asInteger).
duration:= actEnd subtractDate: actStart.
duration = 0 ifTrue: [ duration := 1 ].
values add: duration.
names add: job ].
diagram := GETDiagramBuilder new.
diagram horizontalBarDiagram
  models: values;
  barWidth: 15;
  width: 500;
  color: Color blue;
  regularAxisAsInteger;
  xAxisLabel: 'Days';
  yAxisLabel: 'Activity';
  spacing: 2;
  titleLabel: 'My Chart'.
diagram interaction popUpText.
^diagram open.
```

The method takes aPGResult result from a SQL query and displays horizontal bars.
That all works fine but I want labels using OrderedCollection names on the left of each bar. I tried using the code below as seen on this forum:

```
 values do: [ :value | 
| bar label |
label := ROLabel elementOn: value asString.
diagram rawView add: label.
bar := diagram rawView elementFromModel: value.
ROConstraint move: label onTheLeftOf: bar ].
```

But it gives error: Receiver of position is nil. This means that elementFromModel method cannot find the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GraphET2

```
|builder players scores |
" fake data "
players := #( #Messi #CristianoRonaldo #LuisSuarez #AlexisSanchez #ZlatanIbrahimovic).
scores := players collect: [ :p | {p . (35 atRandom)} ].
scores sort: [ :a :b| a second > b second ].

builder := GET2HorizontalBar data: scores.
builder x: #second; 
        color: Color blue; 
        barWidth: 15;
        title: 'Top 5 - Soccer Scorers';
        width: 500.
builder xAxis formatInteger; title: 'Scores'.
builder yAxis addModelLabels:[:p| p first ]; title: 'Player'.

builder open.
```

[image: Result]

Comment: That's looking good. How can I get this into a Glamour window?

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as correct and create another question for that. This way it will be easier to find about "having a GraphET2 visualisation into a Glamour window" for the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example that, i think, does what you want.

```
|diagram players scores view|
" fake data "
players := #( #Messi #CristianoRonaldo #LuisSuarez #AlexisSanchez #ZlatanIbrahimovic).
scores := (players collect: [ :p | p -> (35 atRandom) ]) asDictionary.
view := ROView new.

diagram := GETDiagramBuilder new.
diagram horizontalBarDiagram
  models: (scores values sort: [:a :b | a > b]);
  barWidth: 15;
  width: 500;
  color: Color blue;
"  regularAxisAsInteger; <-- replaced by the two following lines"
 baseAxisLine;
valueAxisLine;
  xAxisLabel: 'Scores';
  yAxisLabel: 'Players';
  spacing: 2;
  titleLabel: 'Top 5 - Soccer Scorers'.
diagram interaction popUpText.

" We need to generate the graphic elements to customize it "
diagram  openIn: view.

" Now graphic elements do exist, lets add the labels"
scores keysAndValuesDo: [ :player :goals | 
    | bar label |
    label := ROLabel elementOn: player asString.
    diagram rawView add: label.
    bar := diagram rawView elementFromModel: goals.
    ROConstraint move: label onTheLeftOf: bar ].

" Small display tweak due to Ibrahimociv is a long lastname, and open it"
(view translateBy: 120@0) open.
```

The result is this:
[image: Top 5 Soccer Scorers example]

It is cumbersome to add those labels in GraphET, in GraphET2 is quite easier. I will publish an example in GraphET2 tomorrow.

Does it help you?

Comment: Thanks that worked in your example, but I need the regularAxisAsInteger labels and when I changed it back the names appeared all over the place.

Comment: I can get that with GraphET but it will be very hacky. I have a better solution using GraphET2, i will publish it as a different answer.